# I am using org.owasp.esapi in a project and I want to change the ESAPI.properties file such that it can whitelist '&' in the encoder, Can you help me

Tags: java, owasp, whitelist, encoder, esapi

I am using `org.owasp.esapi` in a java project. I am using the `ESAPI.encoder().forHTML()` method for encoding the user input but  this method encodes the '&' to "&" but I do not want to change the '&' so I want to whitelist the '&' character that the encoder does not encode it. So how can I change the ESAPI.properties file such that the encoder will whitelist this method.

please help me to find the properties which whitelist any character.

Answer (score 0):

ESAPI intentionally doesn't provide an easy way for you to white-list additional characters. Many have asked for that without realizing the ramifications. (In this case, it could allow for attacks that come from double-encoding.) So the only way to do that is to write your own encoder to replace `org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder` by specifying your own class for the **ESAPI.Encoder** property and we certainly do *NOT* recommend you doing that.

That said, if I may ask, what specific problem are you trying to solve here? Usually there is just a specific field or two where some character they are required to allow to be rendered is one that is normally blocked and it comes out to be double-encoded so '&' shows up as '&amp;' for instance. If you explain what the specific context is that you want to do, we can suggest alternatives that would be less dangerous than what you are suggesting.

Comment: I want to remove the encoding of '&' from the address field given by the user while displaying on the web as HTML content as the address can contain the '&' sign. I am working on an enterprise-level project (a JAVA backend) which is needed to be protected, the org.owasp.esapi is the only encoding module securely checked and allowed to use by the organization in this project. So I just want to modify the encoding of '&' in the most effective and efficient way. It will be very helpful for me If you can help, Thanks.

Comment: I am adding a second "answer" (one that I am hesitant to do so because there's a better than even chance this will may come back to bite you in terms of XSS), but the reply is too long for just a comment. So see my alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative approach. I do not recommend this because it is difficult to get correct. Have an expert at XSS check review your code and then do some extensive testing using DAST tools or manual pen testing using something like OWASP ZAP or Portswigger Burp Suite.

**Warning**: I did *not* check any of this code or even try to compile it, so you have been warned!

Second to the warning, I don't recall ever seeing a legitimate address that required a '&', so perhaps this is just some edge use case that I don't fully understand. But as I said in my first answer, there is a reason why ESAPI does not allow users to specify their own set of "immune" characters that are excluded from being encoded.

That said, you can do this if you wish to write a *custom* encoder, but depending on what other special characters you want you 'address' to allow (e.g., probably '-', ',', and '.', but hopefully not ';' or '%'), there may be a simpler way and that is to just use strict allow-list custom validation.

You can do that by adding a custom regular expression to your ESAPI '**validation.properties**' file. For example, maybe something like this:

```
# Allow any combination of upper or lower case alphabetic chars, digits, space,
# common, period, ampersand, or hypen. Require a length between 8 and 256 characters.
Validator.Address="^[A-Za-z0-9 ,.&-]{8,256}$"
```

(Note: If you want '-' to be allowed, you **MUST** place it as the very *first* or very *last* character in the character class of your regex.)

Then you would use that regex in combination with either one of the `Validator.getValidInput` or `Validator.isValidInput` methods.

```
String allowedAddr = ESAPI.validator().getValidInput(
                        "Customer address",     // descriptive name for logs
                        addressParam,           // actual user input
                        "Address"               // name of your regex
                        false,                  // no null / empty strings
                        true);                  // canonicalize input before validation
```

Just keep in mind that the safety of this very much depends on what characters you want to allow in your address.

Also, there is a possibility that the last argument may need to be 'false' as there is a possibility that an '&' in your `addressParam` input may trigger it depending on the settings of your **ESAPI.properties** files.